# Why does Svnkit ignore externals when updating to a specific revision?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I'm trying to export a specific revsion of an online SVN Repository using Java 1.7 and SVNkit 1.7.4v1. But the problem is that SVNkit ignores the externals if the specific revision is not HEAD. With the HEAD-revison, the export works fine and externals are included.

I used `UpdateClient.doExport()` as well as `UpdateClient.doCheckout()` and both are having the same problem.

My sample code:

```
setupSVNKit();
SVNClientManager cm = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
SVNURL url = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("https://xxxxxxxx");
File dstPath = new File("d:/svntest");
SVNUpdateClient uc = cm.getUpdateClient();
uc.setIgnoreExternals(false);

/*
uc.doExport(url, dstPath,
SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNRevision.create(11768),
null, true, SVNDepth.INFINITY);
*/

uc.doCheckout(url, dstPath, SVNRevision.UNDEFINED,
    SVNRevision.create(11768), SVNDepth.INFINITY, true);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? Because I need the externals.

Answer (score 1):

Please, file an issue at http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issues/SVNKIT.
I can't reproduce the problem, but if externals are ignored depending on a revision, it is definitely a bug.